# Linq to SQL: Combining objects through a summation of one field only

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I have a set of objects that I'm returning via a Linq to SQL query. I'd like to modify the query so that I return a set of objects that are combined only when one of the fields match.

The relevant columns of my `Products` DB table are `CategoryID` and `Quantity`. I'd like to combine the fields so that if the `CategoryID` is identical, the `Quantity` fields are summed up. However, I don't just want the sum - I need an object that has all the common fields (assume all other fields are identical for the query) so it appears as only one object of type `Product`.

Is this possible? (I'm using VB.net - but open to solutions that include database views, partial classes, etc)

Comment: Just curious, why would you need this? If some fields are always identical for products within a category, looks like they're better off at `Categories` table.

Comment: This seems very abstract to me. Can you show some sample data that shows two products with the same CategoryID, and what the result should be? Which product's "common fields" should be shown?

Comment: This is rather abstract, yes. The common fields are only common because the query has filtered for them (Don't worry about the semantics of `Product` as it relates to design).

Comment: Still very hard to answer your question without providing some sample data and how the results of the query against that data should end up. If you want to leave it as an abstract question, do you expect non-abstract answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to Group on CategoryId and create a new Product based on aggregate data. E.g. (sorry if my VB is terrible):

```
From product In db.Products _
Group By CategoryID = product.CategoryID Into Group _
Select New Product With _
    CategoryID = CategoryID, _
    QuantityA = Group.Select(Function(p) p.QuantityA).Sum(), _
    QuantityB = Group.Select(Function(p) p.QuantityB).Sum()
```

Comment: Yep, this was it, thank you! I know it was a rather abstract question, and I'm finding group syntax in VB.net/Linq rather confusing :/